# insert form to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have program codeigniter anda i want to insert form to database.

code view:

```
<form target="paypal" method="post">
        <div class="field1">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Nama</label>
            <input placeholder="Nama" name="nama" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>No. HP</label>
            <input placeholder="No. HP" name="handphone" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Alamat</label>
            <input placeholder="alamat" name="alamat" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Jumlah</label>
             <div class="selectbox">
                <select name="jumlah" id="">
                <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </select>   
             </div>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="ui teal button order-button">Order now</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

code controller

```
function simpanOrder()
{
    $this->load->model("M_order");
    $data['nama'] = $_POST['nama'];
    $data['handphone'] = $_POST['handphone'];
    $data['alamat'] = $_POST['alamat'];
    $data['jumlah'] = $_POST['jumlah'];


    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $this->M_order->insert($data);
    }
}
```

when i click submit data not insert to database. so can you help me with this code problem? thanks.

Comment: Uhm ... im unsure how this can work without any SQLs.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I'm not saying it's a well written question because it's not, but I presume the function call `$this->M_order->insert($data);` is calling the insert function in his model.

Comment: `isert()` in his M_order class is probably going to push it towards the dataabse. It's hard to give decent answers while guessing what is happening though. You'll need to give at least more information about M_order class. Also you're setting $_POST['nama'] etc before you actually checked if you had a post submitted. If you don't wan't errors/notices, you should set your $data array inside that if() check.

Comment: @user3040066 Please don't write query in controller, always use model for query.

Comment: @Maulikpatel - he hasn't written a query in the controller. He's passing the data to a function in his model?

Comment: @Stanyer Pass data in $this->db->insert(yourtablname, $data); which i mention below answer.

Comment: @Maulikpatel his code is: `$this->M_order->insert($data);`

Comment: @Stanyer this:$this->M_order->insert($data); call controller to model but in model he has to write query for insert in database $this->db->insert(yourtablname, $data);

Comment: I don't get what the problem is? He's passing the data from the controller to the model, the model is then passing the data into the insert function of Active Record. What are you suggesting is incorrect about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't have an action, and therefore may not be going to the function you want it to. (*/controller/function*)

```
<form target="paypal" method="post">
```

Also, instead of using a button to submit the form - try using `<input type="submit"...`
Using the `<button>`, in some browsers, you would have "submit" submitted, in others, "Order now".

If the above doesn't work - check your SQL.

As a side note, CodeIgniter has a `form` helper and a `form_validation` library which are quite useful if you're already using CodeIgniter. That won't fix your problem but it's just something I felt I would point out.

See:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

Call model from controller. and write below code in model.

```
$data = array(
            'handphone' => $this->input->post('handphone'),
            'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
              )
```

In this array key is database columnname.

```
$this->db->insert(yourtablname, $data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: I'am agree with Maulik patel. I recommend placing queries in models. regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to define action attribute in form tag where you will provide controller name and method name like this

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('controllername/simpanOrder')?>" method="post">
```

After posting you can debug your code like this

```
$post = $this->input->post();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($post);
```

Then

```
if($this->input->post('submit')){
    $this->M_order->insert($data);
}
```

And finally

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

This will display you the last query run.